# the form value can't input to mysql, but can connect mysql (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to diy a php quiz, when you have full grade, you may input your information to my database, but when I have filled the form and put the sumbit. Have this error~

Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\record.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\record.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\record.php on line 19
mysql_connect.inc.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
//資料庫設定
//資料庫位置
$db_server = "localhost";
//資料庫名稱
$db_name = "quiz";
//資料庫管理者帳號
$db_user = "root";
//資料庫管理者密碼
$db_passwd = "123456";

//對資料庫連線
if(!@mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_passwd))
        die("can't connect mysql");

//資料庫連線採UTF8
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

//選擇資料庫
if(!@mysql_select_db($db_name))
        die("can't connect db");
?>
```

record.php

```
<?php  ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
session_start();

include("mysql_connect.inc.php");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123456");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin', '35')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire', '33')");

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

 mysql_close($con)
?>
```

process.php

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {

    width:950px;
     height:auto;
     padding: 13px;
     margin-right:auto;
     margin-left:auto;
     background-color:#fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<?php 

    $fid = $_GET['id'];

?>
<body bgcolor="#e1e1e1">

<div id="wrapper">

<center><font face="Andalus" size="5">Your Score</font></center>
<br />
<br />

<?php
    $answer1= $_POST['answerOne'];
    $answer2= $_POST['answerTwo'];
    $answer3= $_POST['answerThree'];
    $score = 0;

    if ($answer1 == "A"){$score++;}
    if ($answer2 == "B"){$score++;}
    if ($answer3 == "C"){$score++;}
    echo "<center><font face='Berlin Sans FB' size='8'>Your Score is <br> $score/3</font></center>";

?>

<br>
<br>
<Center>
<?php   
  if ($score == 3)
    { 
      echo " 
      <form action='record.php' method='post' >
       ID: <input type='text' id='firstname'/><br>
       Phone: <input type='text' id='lastname'/><br>
       E-mail: <input type='text' id='age'/><br><br>
       <input type='submit' value='Submit Data' />
      </form>  ";
    }
?>
</Center>


</div><!--- end of wrapper div --->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Follow it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785519/variables-occasionally-empty-how-to-prevent-undefined-variable-error/15785579#15785579

Answer (score 1):

Your input fields need to have a "name" attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to quote the array keys.

```
$_POST['firstname'] ...
```

Comment: That's not actually required when inside double quotes but you could also do this inside double quotes `"blabla {$_POST['name']} blabla"`

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\record.php on line 12`
I have changed, but have this error.

Comment: @Danny They ARE required. They should actually raise a Warning if ommited, specifying that there is no such constant, and that a string is ASSUMED.

Answer (score 0):

- First off, `('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')` should be `("$_POST[firstname]","$_POST[lastname]","$_POST[age]")` The " " in stead of ' ' get variables inside parsed. Otherwise you would litteraly be inserting $.... inside your database in stead of the contents of the variable.
- Secondly, as stated by Vidario
  You need quotes for the array index. Meaning `$_POST[firstname]` should become `$_POST['firstname']` or `$_POST["firstname"]`. And since we already have " " around the variable already, lets use ' ' for the index now.

So now you have:

```
`("$_POST['firstname']","$_POST['lastname']","$_POST['age']")`
```

- Third, like Danny stated, in the HTML you need to give the inputs a name, so they can be used in PHP. Id is not enough. So `<input type="..." id="blah" name="blah" />`

Answer (score -1):

Replace this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
```

with this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST['firstname']','$_POST['lastname']','$_POST['age']')";
```

And add name attributes to your form like this:

```
<?php   
if ($score == 3)
{ 
  echo " 
  <form action=\'record.php\' method=\'post\' >
   ID: <input type=\'text\' name=\'firstname\' id=\'firstname\'><br>
   Phone: <input type=\'text\' name=\'lastname\' id=\'lastname\'><br>
   E-mail: <input type=\'text\' name=\'age\' id=\'age\'><br><br>
   <input type=\'submit\' value=\'Submit Data\'>
  </form>  ";
}
?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\record.php on line 12`
I have changed, but have this error.

Comment: @DanteMan Just a question, why are you inserting Peter Griffin and Glenn Quagmire to your DB every time you submit the form?

Comment: Just for test the database...But the form can't input the data on database. thx u

Comment: So the Peter and Glenn do not get inserted in the database?

Comment: Peter and Glenn can get inserted in the database, but the form value can't. could you use my php file do again?

Comment: `'$_POST['firstname']'` ? try using " instead of ' for outer apostrophes

Comment: and remove those backslashes `\` that Daanvn added in the <form> !